# Integral solutions to $x^2+y^2 = 10^{10}$

Tags: number-theory

Is there an efficient way to find the number of integral solutions to $x^2+y^2 = 10^{10}$. The only possible way I can think of is brute force, but that is highly inefficient. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: In fact, there is a formula : https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SumofSquaresFunction.html

Comment: Note $10^{10} = \left(10^5\right)^2$, so the solutions to your equation would be [Pythagorean triples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple).

Comment: You can use factorizations in $\mathbb Z[i]$.

Comment: quick lemma is that multiplying by $2$ does not change the number of its representations as $x^2 + y^2.$ So, you should carefully find the numbers of representations of $1, 5, 25, 125$ and see what happens. You'll learn something

Comment: @Wojowu I see that I can rewrite this as $(x+iy)(x-iy) = 10^10$ but how does that help me? Can you explain further.

Comment: the solution of this is the solution of $m^{2}+n^{2}=5^{10}$ multiplied by $2^{10}$

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja no, multiplying a number by $2$ or $4$ or any power of $2$ does not change the number of representations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$|\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}^2: x^2+y^2=n \}|:=r_2(n)=4\sum_{d|n} \sin \bigg(\frac{\pi}{2}d \bigg)$$

Note that all even divisors result in no change to the number of solutions.

$$r_2(10^{10})=r_2(5^{10})=4\times 11 =44$$

Wolfram alpha can evaluate [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=r_2%285%5E10%29).

Comment: An animated explanation for the formula for $r_2$ can be found [here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NaL_Cb42WyY&t=1512s)

Comment: There is a very clean version in Introduction to Number Theory, about 1929 I think, by Leonard E. Dickson. Been reprinted, cheap.